# send command to zebra printer xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, printers

How would I send a CPCL or ZPL command to a Zebra printer through an app?
These commands would be similar to ones used in ToolBox.

For example how would I send "! U1 getvar "allcv"" to a printer and get the results.

I am using the Link-OS ios SDK and already have no problems connecting to and printing to the printers.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: Personally I've never tried to use CPCL via Objective-C and have only played with it via C# as well as over telnet. With that said I have to ask if you're escaping the quotes inside the command. I seem to remember having issues over telnet where I had to use the ASCII character value for the quotes instead of escaping them for whatever reason.

Comment: Also, which model printer are you using?

Comment: I'm testing this on a QLn320 printer and have tried escaping quotes.

Comment: I've seen c# code of this and from what I understand I need to send the command as a bye stream to the printer.

Comment: You're going to make me fire up VS, aren't you? ;)

In the meantime what happens if you use %c & 34 to substitue via ASCII?

Comment: Looks like you're right... when I implemented this 3 years ago for the Mz-series I sent the commands as a byteStream and did in fact escape my quotes. For the telnet hack I created I used ASCII values.

Comment: Is this the only command not working or are none of the get/set commands working?

Comment: none of them, I cannot seem to send or receive data

Comment: Also - is it safe to assume you're consuming the response in your code? I want to say allcv doesn't dump a printout but returns the dump real-time.

Comment: You are correct about allcv, but for testing purposes I've changed the command to "! U1 setvar \"device.reset\" \"\"<CR><LF>"

Comment: Note: that is an escaped string and should just reset the device

Comment: I got the reset to work, but now need to read the "allcv" command back as a string

Comment: I can't seem to get the data back. I've tried reading back the bytes but just get null. The toString ethod just returns the address and port number.\

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure this out? It's quite simple in the *nix world. If you send commands to the lp port via `cat` or some such, the printer will simply read them in. Note that this must be done as root if you don't have permissions set up on the device to allow normal users.

```
$ sudo cat command_file.txt > /dev/usb/lp0
```

So, I'm not a C or C++ developer, but the idea is the same in any language. Open the file for writing (probably `O_RDWR` so you can read back in any response from the printer) and then send commands to the fd returned from open().

You didn't specify an OS so I'll just stick with this *nix answer. That said, it wouldn't be different in Windows, I suppose. You just have to be able to find the right device.

Comment: Hey Jim. I was actually able to find a method in the SDK which worked. However your linux implementation is very interesting. Thanks!